# Store data into google drive's backup tab instead of drive folders

Tags: whatsapp, google-drive-android-api, drive, android-backup-service

I need to implement same thing like whatsapp storing all chat history to google drive on clicking on backup button in app. And same restore it in new device as required.

I have look for below references for implementing this, but some how I was not able to do it successfully.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Will this data backup option will help in my requirements or I need to do something else?

I successfully developed the file upload to google drive folders, but i need that data in the backup tab of google drive with app name.

can any one guide me how I can implement this or provide me some references?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: have you solved this can you share some code how you solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata). The Google Drive API includes a special hidden folder that your app can use to store application data.

> **Note:** This feature now uses the alias **`appDataFolder`** in place of **`appdata`** and **`appfolder`**.

To be able to use your Application Data folder, request access to the following scope:

> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`

For more information about scopes and how to request access to them, see [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).